# Improving productivity and performance of Text based XML renderer

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm trying to write an efficient XML render for XML.Light data types, and I am trying to do this with `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder` as this seems an obvious choice. However, I'm having a hard time getting any performance out of my solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text (Text, unpack)
import Text.XML.Light
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LT
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Builder as LB

import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

data Tag = Tag !Text

data Artist = Artist { artistName :: !Text , artistTags :: ![Tag] }

class ToXML a where toXML :: a -> Content

instance ToXML Artist where
  toXML a = Elem $
    Element (unqual "artist") []
      [ text (artistName a)
      , Elem $ Element (unqual "tag-list") []
          (map toXML (artistTags a))
          Nothing
      ]
      Nothing

instance ToXML Tag where
  toXML (Tag t) = Elem $ Element (unqual "tag") [] [ text t ] Nothing

text :: Text -> Content
text t = Text $ CData CDataText (unpack t) Nothing

render :: Content -> LB.Builder
render (Elem e) = renderElement e
render (Text s) = LB.fromString (cdData s)

renderElement :: Element -> LB.Builder
renderElement element = mconcat
  [ LB.singleton '<'
  , LB.fromString . qName . elName $ element
  , LB.singleton '>'
  , foldMap render (elContent element)
  , LB.fromText "</"
  , LB.fromString . qName .elName $ element
  , LB.singleton '>'
  ]

main :: IO ()
main = let artist = Artist "Nirvana" (replicate 5000000 (Tag "Hi"))
           xml = Element (unqual "metadata") [] [ toXML artist ] Nothing
       in print (LT.length . LB.toLazyText . renderElement $ xml)
```

According to `+RTS -s`:

```
   7,368,153,472 bytes allocated in the heap
   2,625,983,944 bytes copied during GC
     708,149,024 bytes maximum residency (13 sample(s))
      21,954,496 bytes maximum slop
            1443 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     14270 colls,     0 par    1.65s    1.69s     0.0001s    0.0009s
  Gen  1        13 colls,     0 par    2.57s    2.80s     0.2157s    1.2388s

  TASKS: 3 (1 bound, 2 peak workers (2 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.81s  (  1.84s elapsed)
  GC      time    4.22s  (  4.50s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.07s  (  0.09s elapsed)
  Total   time    6.11s  (  6.43s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,064,658,288 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  30.8% of total user, 29.3% of total elapsed
```

Which is awful. Not only is that rock bottom productivity, over 7GiB are allocated in the heap to render 64MB of XML. That seems wildly inefficient! However, I have no idea where all of this garbage is actually coming from. I generated a heap profile with `+RTS -p` and rendered it with `hp2ps`:

[image: Heap profile]

And I also ran it with `+RTS -l` and rendered this with ThreadScope:

[image: ThreadScope rendering of event log]

What I sadly don't know how to do now, is put these pieces together to get this productivity up, and memory usage down. I do wonder if the types in `XML.Light` are less than optimal (no strictness, `String` over `Text`) but still - *this* slow?

---

I have also observed something else that I find a little strange. If I change `main` to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = let artist = Artist "Nirvana" (replicate 5000000 (Tag "Hi"))
           xml = Element (unqual "metadata") [] [ toXML artist ] Nothing
       in print (LT.length $ LB.toLazyText $ mconcat $ map (render.toXML) $ artistTags artist)
```

Productivity shoots up to 94%, so maybe it's something to do with recursing in `toXML` that is problematic and is overly lazy.

Comment: You know that `artistTags :: ![Tag]` doesn't force much, do you? Just enough to see whether the list is empty or not. You could try forcing `(map toXML (artistTags a))` in the `Artist` instance (deepseq or so). That could help or hurt, don't know off-hand. `foldMap render (elContent element)` could also have a part in it, but generally, `text` is pretty efficient, so I don't count that among the prime suspects.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem, and I think it's a bug in GHC.

If we change this line:

```
, LB.fromString . qName . elName $ element
```

Into this:

```
, LB.fromString $ qName . elName $ element
```

Then we get the performance we'd expect. It seems that composing `LB.fromString` with `qName` prevents some inlining and thus fusion doesn't happen. I think this is really dangerous, so I'm going to move this question to a bug report on GHCs bug tracker and see what the wise folk over there think.

Talk about a gotcha!